# "Sequential", "procedural" and "planner" in German: difference between words and their translations

Tags: english-to-german

For a vocabulary list I'm making I need to translate the words "sequential" (adj.), "procedural" (adj.) and "planner" (n.). All are being used in the context of describing people, but I haven't been able to come up with any German words that are also used to describe people. (For instance, sequential can translate to "sequentiell", but I don't know if that's OK for describing people with.)

My best guesses would be something like this:

> sequential, procedural: schrittbezogen (bzgl. eines Plans)
>
> planner: "Planmacher"

but I want to differentiate between the two words "sequential" and "procedural". Also, I don't think "Planmacher" is used very often. So any help would be appreciated.

--

Edit: Here are some examples I came up with to try to illustrate what I mean.

> She is a "planner"--before attempting any task, she has to have a detailed plan in mind in how to complete the task.
>
> We work procedurally--we focus all our efforts on one specific task, and only after its completion do we move on to the next task.
>
> He is very sequential in his thought processes, thinking of one thing at a time in a logical order.

Comment: Could we have a bit more context or examples, please?

Comment: @Stephie See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, you may use the adjective *methodisch* or related words:

> durchdacht, geplant, gezielt, methodisch, nach Plan, plangemäß, planmäßig, planvoll, schrittweise, systematisch, taktisch, überlegt

For example, *„methodisch vorgehen“* means ‘proceed methodically’.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "sequentiell", "prozedural", and "Planer". They are fine for describing people. "Schrittbezogen" doesn't really make sense, and "Planmacher" sounds awkward.

However, from your description, I can't really destinguish between the intended meaning of "sequential" and "procedural". I'd describe "move to the next task only after completion of the previous task" as typically sequential behaviour, while I'd define procedural behaviour along the lines of "sticks to a number of 'recipes' and follows them, instead of coming up with a new unique approach for every problem".